# Magento makes 307 redirect to HTTPS instead of 301

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, 301-redirect, redirect-url

I have set my whole frontend to use HTTPS. But in the headers I see that if I go to **http**://example.com Magento redirects me to the HTTPS version using **307** redirect. I tried to change this by setting in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it didn't help.

What should I do to make Magento use **301** redirect instead of **307**?

(I am using CE 1.9.1.0)

Comment: do you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 307 redirect is in real a `307 Internal Redirect` done by the Chrome Browser because the domain is known to require/support `Strict Transport Security`

So its not done by your Magento.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068418/whats-the-difference-between-a-302-and-a-307-redirect/29988907#29988907

Answer (score 0):

A typo in your sites configuration (maybe in your vhost settings for your webserver), it is nowhere defined in Magento.

Did a `grep -R 307` in a clean Magento and found nothing related to your problem.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068418/whats-the-difference-between-a-302-and-a-307-redirect

Comment: I did that too before posting here. Strangely it seems to happen only in Chrome and Opera Chromium.

Comment: I found a other stack page where the answer is very clear, I think you would take a look there(edited my question)

Comment: Thanks. I know what redirect codes mean :) But that is not the question.

Comment: The answers where more specific about particular browsers